# C# select item of combobox by ID

Tags: c#, combobox, devexpress

I have this class

```
   class ComboboxValue
    {
        public int Id { get; private set; }
        public string Name { get; private set; }

        public ComboboxValue(int id, string name)
        {
            Id = id;
            Name = name;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Name;
        }

    }
```

and I set my entries like this:

```
 var list = Funktionen.LoadCustomers();
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            MyCombo.Properties.Items.Add(new ComboboxValue(item.ID, item.Name));
        }
```

In another function, I will set a item in my combobox by customerID. 
How can I do this?
Btw. I´m using Devexpress.

Thank you.

Comment: What is `customerID`?

Comment: Sorry, LoadCustomers() returns this class Customers{public int ID, public string Name}

Comment: LoadCustomers() should return List<Customers>

Comment: thats right, it do so. But how do I select the item by an external ID? MyCombo.SelectedItem = ...?

Comment: Could you explain a little what you want to do and how?

Comment: you want select an ID from combobox?

Answer (score 1):

To programmatically select a value for the combo, set the ComboBoxEdit.EditValue property. Here is some sample code:

```
ComboBoxEdit.EditValue = 2;  // select an item which ID = 2
```

Besides the Selected index you can use the [SelectedItem](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsComboBoxEdit_SelectedItemtopic) property to select any item within the editor's item list. You need to assign an underlying data object to the SelectedItem property.

Alternatively, you can set its EditValue to '25' that is the ValueMember property value of the desirable item as shown in above example.

Reference these:
[Select Item in ComboBoxEdit](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q294304)
[how set combobox selected value](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q341970)

Answer (score 1):

**To select item in ComboboxValue class :**

```
comboBox1.SelectedItem = comboBox1.Items.Cast<ComboboxValue>()
    .Where(i => i.Name == dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value.ToString()).Single();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var item = MyCombo.Properties.Items.FirstOrDefault(i => i.ID == yoursearchIDhere);
```

item will be combobox item which you want to get. If you look for it or not, let me know and explain clearly please
LoadCustomers() should return List also.

Comment: Sorry, I will select an item in my filled comboboy by an external ID.

Comment: MyComba.EditValue=yourExternalID;

Answer (score 0):

Try
`MyCombo.SelectedItem = MyCombo.Items.SingleOrDefault(x => (x as ComboboxValue).Id == externalID)`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this piece of code may answer the question, it is better to include a description of what the problem was, and how your code will tackle the given problem. For the future, here is some information, [how to crack a awesome answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) on Stack Overflow.